# Can we make pinch gesture in android core system programatically without touching being service on background?

Tags: android, android-studio, gesture

I've a question regarding pinch gesture in android system. I've a task regarding pinch zoom in and out in android app without touching screen. In android we can detect for pinch gesture but can we produce gesture without touching programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could, but you wouldn't do it that way.  In your touch code, you'd be detecting a gesture.  When that gesture is detected, you do something.  Take that something, turn it into a function.  Then when you want to produce that gesture programatically, just call that function instead.  No need to do something complicated and possible to fail like faking a gesture.  Just architect your code properly and its all avoided.